# HighChart Combination Column Spline Backed by JSF Bean

Tags: java, json, highcharts, gson

in a backing bean for a HighChart page, I query database and set the chart data as such:

```
    series.add(new Series("Series1", chartDao.getData1()));
    series.add(new Series("Series2", chartDao.getData2()));
    setChartData(new Gson().toJson(series)); //For HighCharts
```

Series is pojo with `name` and `data` properties.

In chart.xhtml in the HighChart section I have

```
    chart: { type: column,
    ...
    series: $.parseJSON(${chartController.chartData})
```

this works but now I want to send along another set of series overlaid as a spline.

I modified my Series object to include color and type and then in my backing bean do

```
    series.add(new Series("Series1", chartDao.getData1(), "blue", "column"));
    series.add(new Series("Series2", chartDao.getData2(), "red", "column"));
    series.add(new Series("Series3", chartDao.getData3(), "yellow", "spline"));
    series.add(new Series("Series4", chartDao.getData4(), "green", "spline"));
```

This works too but is it the right way? I'm wondering if there is a better way because very time I want to tweak my chart it seems like I have to modify my Series object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution looks pretty good to me. The problem I think you are worried about is that you had to modify your Series constructor because you wanted to tweak one of the series settings.

An alternative to this would be to add methonds on your Series object to modify the various settings:

```
Series s = new Series("Series1", chartDao.getData1());
s.setColor("blue");
s.setType("column");
s.setYAxis(0);
...
series.add(s);
```

This way, you only need to call the new methods for those series which need it, rather than modifying every series constructor (e.g. column could be the default type).

Alternatively, you could check out some existing wrappers for highcharts here: http://www.highcharts.com/download. There is at least one java wrapper listed there.

Comment: yes, I guess that is what I am worried about.  Also, it seems like I need to make "LineSeries extends Series" and "ColumnSeries extends Series" since setting a line dashed property on a Series of type Column does not make sense.  Ideally I'd like to figure out a way to pass in different sets of series and stylize them in the Javascript.

Comment: There is an existing java wrapper for highchartswhich may do what you want. http://www.highcharts.com/download